# Is this a possible race with select/poll/epoll/kqueue?

Tags: c, unix, file-io, concurrency

I'm studying the semantics of [select()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html)/[poll()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html)/[epoll()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) and [kqueue()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) to decide how to emulate them in user space for my [operating system](http://jehanne.io/).

Note that I only care about **file read/write/exceptions** multiplexing, not signals, child process states, timers and so on...

I've read several resource about them, their comparison, their advantages and their issues, but I can't find anything about a particular race that to my understanding affects all of them.

Suppose you have a multiplexing process waiting in a `select` (or in any other of group) for a file to be readable. After the `select` returns, but before the process can `read` that specific fd, another process sharing that same descriptor `read` the file. As far as I can tell, the `read` in the multiplexing process will block (until more data are available).

I know that this is a bug in the application (the multiplexed descriptors should not be available to any other process concurrently using them) but still I'd like to know if it's a possible scenario and if the various operating systems do anything to prevent such race.
Indeed, despite being probably complex, they **could** prevent the race, for example blocking the read of a particular descriptor "returned as readable" by `select` on all but the multiplexing process, till such process has consumed the event (aka `read` the fd). Obviously for more exotic events, this may be impossible, but I'm considering only files reads/writes here.

**Note:** this question is about the race, not the specifics of each system call, so please do not try to explain the differences/advantages and so on, if they are not related to this particular race.

**Edit** To clarify, I'm thinking about files that can actually block on read/write, since as explained by the select(2) manual on Linux

> A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a
>   corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2) without blocking, or
>   sufficiently small write(2)).

Comment: Processes doesn't really share descriptors, even if they are related (e.g. forked) and have the same number and reference the same file. It's still two distinct descriptors with their own buffering. Another process might still delete or modify the file between the polling and the reading or writing of the file, leading to other problems.

Comment: Well AFAIK, this is not true for all Unix derivative (at least it's not true for Plan 9... :-D).   
Still I'm not sure this answer my question for Linux/BSD either: since you don't tell the kernel how much your are going to read, how buffers could be relevant?

Comment: Well buffers aren't really relevant, but what's is important is that it's two distinct and different file descriptors. Having two processes (no matter if one was forked from another) reading from the same file is simply not a problem. One process will not block the other if both are only reading from the file.

Comment: Unless the file descriptor is non-blocking you can block in read regardless of what poll&co returns. Also, poll&co are meaningless on normal files and will (or at least should) return that the file is always readable. The answer is: no one does anything to prevent this race because it's a meaningless race. In a real scenario when one thread is in poll and the other one reads from the fd, the polling thread will at worst wake up, read from the fd, get an error because the fd is non-blocking and go back into poll.

Comment: @Art I tried to clarify that I'm obviously thinking about file descriptors that can block on read/write.

Comment: Actually, to add to my previous comment. Very old implementations of select on quite a few systems had spurious wakeups where select could report a file descriptor readable despite there not being anything to read from it. It hasn't been a problem for decades, but nothing prevents you from having two threads poll on the same fd or have the same fd twice in one poll call. The general idea with select/poll/etc has always been that you must be aware of the TOCTOU issue and deal with it. That's why poll&co on anything that isn't non-blocking is almost always an error.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio That manual page lies. You can have a read block for ever on an NFS file despite select always returning true for them. Also, every read can always block for other things, like locks, memory, etc. Waiting for the disk to get your data for example isn't considered blocking even though it can take quite some time. The term "blocking" isn't very well defined, it should be something like "wait for data to become available that doesn't have a reasonable upper bound in time".

Comment: @Art probably the sum of your comments qualify as an answer: this is a well known race that programmers are expected to know and avoid. Do you mind to write it down as such. Note that I'm also interested in the historical backgrounds. Given what you wrote, I'm a bit surprised that this family of system calls is not a common cause/target of DoS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

When reading through file ,read will automatically return once EOF is reached.Whether this question is related to SOCKET reading?